# Blow up of a solution

Tags: soft-question, terminology, partial-differential-equations

What exactly does blow up mean, when people say, for example, that a solution (to a pde (say)) blows up.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, my understanding of "blow-up" in the context of partial differential equations is that is what happens when, due to singularities inherent in the set of solutions to a PDE, inaccuracies in the approximate solution appear when attempting to approximate the solution with a mesh. Usually this is because the user of the algorithm for solving the PDE may have failed to use the proper dependent variables, neglected to factor out singular behavior, or any number of other things.

Comment: Shibi, I think you're asking about blowup in PDEs, which is much more specific and well-defined than "blow up" in the sense several of the answers seem to be taking it. If you could clarify if you mean PDEs, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Katie: "that a solution (to a pde (say)) blows up" Granted, he neglected to capitalize...

Comment: sure but the "say" makes it seem like a PDE is just an arbitrary example of a possible answer that could be of interest, not the actual question. (I don't care to be nitpicky, except that this formulation of the question is receiving answers that vary widely and in un-useful ways in their interpretation of what the question is; see, e.g. Dan Z's comment on his answer.)

Comment: Katie, I did mean it in the sense of PDE's , or in a sense of a function in calculus ( which is the reason I put a say in the brackets). Sorry to have caused the confusion.

Answer (score 29):

The meaning is, of course, context-dependent...

In the context of differential equations, that a solution to an equation with a "time" variable blows up usually means that the maximal domain for which it is defined is finite, so that at the endpoint of that interval something `bad' happens: either the solution goes to infinity, or it stops being smooth (in a way that makes the differential equation stop having sense, maybe), or something. This is an important phenomenon, one which causes trouble. A couple of examples:

- Perelman's solution of the Poincaré conjecture—in a very vague sense—consists of a way to `work around' the fact that certain solutions of a (very complicated non-linear) PDE blow up;
- the third `Millenium' Clay [problem](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Navier-Stokes_Equations/) is (very roughly) the question «do the solutions of the Navier-Stokes equation blow up?».

Consider, as a very simple example, the equation $$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=x^2.$$ This equation makes sense and satisfies the conditions for existence and uniqueness of solutions on all of the $(t,x)$-plane, but if you solve it (which is easy to do explicitely, as it has the two variabls separated) you'll see that all of its solutions have a maximal interval which is a half-line (which is bounded on the left or on the right, depending on the initial condition) and that at the finite end of that interval the solutions become unbounded. We thus say that all solutions of our equation blow up in finite time.

There are also equations which have *some* solutions which blow up and some which live forever. One example is $$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{if $x\geq0$}\\0&\text{if $x\leq0$}\end{cases}$$ and you'll surely find lots of fun in trying to concoct examples where even more interesting phenomena occur.

Comment: Just adding that in physical system such solutions often mean that it will literally blow up, e.g. due to thermal runaway as shown in http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/pdectb/blowup22.pdf For examples in mechanics there's an entire book by Brian Straughan titled *Explosive Instabilities in Mechanics*.

Answer (score 4):

It means that as time goes on, the response-- be it displacement, velocity, heat, field or whatever-- will also go to infinity.

This is physically impossible and is usually due to the poor numerical/approximated methods use to solve the PDE.

Comment: Such singularities can also occur in "finite time".

Comment: You can't always blame the numerical method; if you use the wrong set of variables (i.e. not figuring out a proper variable substitution), such numerical disasters are likely to happen.

Answer (score 3):

In the context I usually hear it used, it means that a quantity is undefined or goes to infinity in the limit under consideration. For example, a function which has a singularity at that point blows up at that point (or "as *x* goes to" that point).  Essentially, "blows up" indicates that something is being divided by zero. But I never considered it a technical term, just a bit of mathematical street lingo ;-) I do not know if this is *exactly* what is meant when it's used in the context of PDE analysis.

By way of example, I would say the integral

$\int_{r_0}^\infty \frac{1}{r^2}\mathrm{d}r$

blows up when $r_0 = 0$. Or that the function $\frac{1}{r^2}$ blows up at $r = 0$.

Comment: On MathSciNet you will find that "blow up" is in the title of 2122 papers.  My understanding is that it has a fairly technical definition in PDEs.

Comment: Qiaochu: not really that technical I'm afraid; it's much like the concept of "stiffness" for ordinary differential equations: nobody really has a rigorous definition, but people know it when they solve an ODE numerically.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Perhaps it does, I don't know. I interpreted the question as being more general than just PDEs.

Comment: Presumably many of those 2122 papers pertain to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up, a notion in algebraic geometry.

Comment: On the other hand, there's http://books.google.com/books?id=cXH3wTwmygQC&pg=PA3 ; as already mentioned, it has a lot to do with hitting a singularity while going through the mesh of a PDE's approximate solution.

Comment: @Pete: I don't know, but of the papers in the first page only one refers to the algebraic geometric notion and the rest are about PDEs.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I checked -- you're right.  I live in ignorance of PDE's, in particular of the specialized terminology PDEers use.  So far as I know, in the land of P/DE's blowing up just means what happens as you approach a singularity (in other word, what Bill Dubuque said), but if it had a more specialized meaning I would be one of the last to know.

Comment: @Pete: Actually, we may be talking about the same thing.  When a function has a singularity, I would say it blows up at that point - I kind of meant that to be covered under a "quantity going to infinity in the appropriate limit." I'll see if I can reword my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @DZ: Sure, what you say is essentially the same as what I said.

Comment: 'Blowing up' can be done 'to' a PDE solution, or 'by' a solution, and it means different things. Done 'to' a solution it's a limit of stretching transformations, like the notion in algebraic geometry, and is often used to study regularity properties. Done 'by' a solution, it means some quantity becomes infinite as a parameter (time, say) varies.

Answer (score 3):

It denotes a singularity or discontinuity - as opposed to decaying or stable solutions.

Answer (score -2):

"Blows up" means it goes to infinity.

1/x "blows up" at x = 0.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain