# Construct an example of a first-order differential equation on $\mathbb{R}$ for which there are no solutions to any initial value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Construct an example of a first-order differential equation on $\mathbb{R}$ for which
there are no solutions to any initial value problem.

Could anyone please get me started on this. I am struck as to which direction to go

Comment: You want non-existence of solutions *locally* or *globally*; the latter is easy to give examples (I gave a very simple one [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2835/274)); the former, I can't think of anything (due to Carathéodory's existence theorem, for example)

Comment: $(y')^2+1=0$. ${}{}$

Comment: @ André Nicolas: could u explain your answer a little?

Comment: I take it we are talking about functions from the reals to the reals. Since $(y')^2+1\ge 0$ always, there is no (real) solution to the DE $(y')^2+1=0$. Same for $(y')^2+x^2+1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Simply consider $\dot x=f(t)$ where $f$ is [the Dirichlet function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function).

There's no solution for any initial value since $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, while the derivative of a differentiable function should be continuous somewhere.

It's a direct consequence of Baire category theorem, since for any differentiable function $g$, $g'(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(g(t+1/n)-g(t))$, a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions.

For more details, and the continuity of a derivative, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/23875