# Does non-uniqueness of solution to 1st order ODE implies the existence of infinitely many solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the following initial value problem (IVP) to the first order ODE:

$$\tag{1} \dot x = f(t, x), \ \ \ x(t_0) = x_0.$$

The [Existence and Uniqueness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) describes when one has exactly one solutions. This is true (e.g.) when $f$ is continuously differentiable.

There are examples where uniqueness [fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239284/can-a-differential-equation-have-non-unique-solutions) and existence fails ([here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/linear-differential-equation-with-no-solution-to-initial-value-problem/) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668144/construct-an-example-of-a-first-order-differential-equation-on-mathbbr-for)):

In all of the examples where I am aware of, whenever one has more than one solutions, one actually has infinitely many. Hence my question:

Can an IVP has more than one solutions, but only finitely many solutions?

Comment: I am new to this topic , so i will add more details of what i try if i got some ideas

Comment: How about $(y')^2=1$ with $y(0)=0$? The two solutions are $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

Comment: @BarryCipra thanks, but what about first order differential equaltion?

Comment: I don't why there is a negative vote!

Comment: @CloudJR Barry's example IS first order -- it goes by derivatives :) but if your equation is linear, that would be the implication you are looking for

Comment: @gt6989b I'm sorry, i messed up

Comment: @gt6989b, actually my example is not first order, which means the equation is of the form $y'=f(t,y)$, which $y'=\pm1$ is not, since $\pm1$ is not a function. (The OP added "first order" after I posted my comment.)

Comment: @BarryCipra this is incorrect. You are defining **explicit** first order equations, and the one you posted is **implicit** but still first-order. See [Wiki ODE page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)

Comment: @gt6989b, OK, I was going by a restricted definition of "first-order." It does seem clear, from the comments, that the OP is interested in the explicit variety, so the exercise suggested in Artem's answer would seem to be of interest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is positive: in general (apart of some artificial examples) if an IVP for an ODE
$$
\dot x=f(t,x),\quad x(t)\in \mathbb R^n
$$
 have non unique solution it implies that there are uncountably many solutions. In these general setting this is a very nontrivial theorem which can be found in Hartman's book (Kneser's theorem). If, however, you are dealing with an ODE
$$
\dot x=f(t,x),\quad x(0)=x_0,
$$
where $x(t)$ is one-dimensional, it is a good (and simple) exercise to prove that if there are two solutions to this problem then there are infinitely (uncountably) many solutions.

Comment: Well, i will try your exercise!

Comment: @CloudJR Assume that there are two solutions. Draw a picture. Conclude.

Comment: I tried but its not that easy, i'm still stuck...lol

Comment: Could you point me to those artificial examples? I'd love to see exactly how one can break this theorem